# Для чего нужен loader.get_template в Django?

Tags: python, django

loader.get_template для чего нужен данный метод ?

Answer (score 0):

Ищет в по тем путям, которые прописаны в `TEMPLATES["DIRS"]` шаблон, имя которого передаётся в эту функцию, и возвращает объект Template. В документации можно почитать подробнее: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Engine.get_template